# 'webread' Matlab function not found

Tags: matlab, web

I am using Matlab R2010a but could not find 'webread' function but with the message : "Undefined function or variable 'webread'." is shown.
The only available web function is 'web'.
How to download that function or solve the problem anyway?

Comment: Simply upgrading your MATLAB to the newest version (or at least post-R2014b) is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks. You right and I did not notice that, so I have to move to a newer version to work with webread

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the bottom of the [documentation for `webread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) function, it has been introduced only in matlab 2014b.

You might find [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2014/01/17/scraping-data-from-the-web/) (aka [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44751-url-filter)), or [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/03/03/read-data-from-the-web-with-urlread/) helpful as a substitute. I do not know whether any of them will work well on such an old version of Matlab though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The substitutional solution by using urlread worked, but not as good or functional as webread